# Generating JSON with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have 2 txt files, in the first there are all car manufacturers and in the second is every model of the vehicle manufacturer. I would like to get the make/model into a JSON which should look like this:

```
[{"value":"ACURA","title":"Acura","models":
    [{"value":"CL_MODELS","title":"CL Models (4)"},
    {"value":"2.2CL","title":" - 2.2CL"},
    {"value":"2.3CL","title":" - 2.3CL"},
    {"value":"MDX","title":"MDX"},
    {"value":"NSX","title":"NSX"},
    {"value":"RDX","title":"RDX"},
    {"value":"ACUOTH","title":"Other Acura Models"}]},
{"value":"ALFA","title":"Alfa Romeo","models":
    [{"value":"ALFA164","title":"164"},
    {"value":"ALFA8C","title":"8C Competizione"},
    {"value":"ALFAGT","title":"GTV-6"},
    {"value":"MIL","title":"Milano"},
    {"value":"SPID","title":"Spider"},
    {"value":"ALFAOTH","title":"Other Alfa Romeo Models"}]}]
```

Can someone give me the right approach even if I have to do this manually ?
Thank you in advance I would really appreciate your help !

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: What format are your text files in? Can every model be made by every manufacturer? Please edit that in.

Comment: No it cant be made by any manufacturer, these files are just a lists for myself. Im asking here for a code that will generate a JSON that is looking just like the one from above.

Comment: Do you intend to read the files in as part of the code you are writing? If so (and the point of my earlier question) how will you instruct the code to link a manufacturer to the models it makes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encode an array thus:

```
$cars = [
    'ALFA' => [
        'title' => 'Alfa Romeo',
        'models' => [ ... ]
    ],
    'ACURA' => [
        'title' => 'Acura',
        'models' => [ ... ]
    ],
];
```

This can then be run through `json_encode()`.

Answer (score 1):

The process would look like this:
1. Parse the data from the files and save them into array.
2. Use json_encode() on the array.

Without the data format you will not get the code from us. How can help you parse the data not knowing how it looks like :/